# Write form input to .txt file with php?

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I'm trying to write this form's input to a new .txt file with php, without redirecting to a new page. This code is written in index.php and I suppose I can't put that as the 'form action= ' as well (sorry, looking back it feels especially stupid). My Javascript knowledge is limited, but I believe this is a matter for .ajax? A yes or no would be great! And if you know a good place to learn what I need to, even better!

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="email" class="emailSubmitSidebar" placeholder=" Your Email">
     <input type="submit" class="submitButton">
</form>
<?php 
    $fileHandle = fopen('emailList.txt', 'w+')
            OR die ("Can't open file\n");
    $email=$_POST("email");
    $result = fwrite ($fileHandle, $email);
    if ($result)
         {
             print '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
             print 'alert("Email added!")'; 
             print '</script>';  
        } else {
            print '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
            print 'alert("Email not added!")'; 
            print '</script>';  
        };
    fclose($fileHandle);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are using this  `$email=$_POST("email");`
but you have to use this

```
 $email=$_POST["email"];
```

I think Below will help you as par ur comment.
for doing without page load user ajax.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{


    $fileHandle = fopen('emailList.txt', 'w+')
            OR die ("Can't open file\n");
    $email=$_POST["email"];
    $result = fwrite ($fileHandle, $email);
    if ($result)
         {
             print '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
             print 'alert("Email added!")'; 
             print '</script>';  
        } else {
            print '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
            print 'alert("Email not added!")'; 
            print '</script>';  
        };
    fclose($fileHandle);
    }
    ?>

<form action="#" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="email" class="emailSubmitSidebar" placeholder=" Your Email">
     <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submitButton">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, silly mistake! I'm now getting an alert upon first loading the page that the "email (was) not added". How do I make the if/else run only when the button is pressed/when the data is written? Also how do I do this without reloading the page?

Answer (score 1):

The  `$email=$_POST("email");` should be  `$email=$_POST["email"];` .

You are calling the **`$_POST`** global array as a function , which is wrong. Enclose it in square brackets. **`[ ]`** as shown.